Detrend data with R
I am following this code to detrend my data but when I use it, this error appears: 'Error in 1:m : argument of length 0'
If I have two totalWidgets it works, but why does it not work with one?  I only have on column of data but it seems time series works with a minimum of two columns. Is there a way to work with one column only? Thanks
library(pracma)

#Create data frame with country data:

# error with one total widgets
a1 <- data.frame( "totalWidgets"=c(5,10,9,1,3,1,6,9,6,5,
                                   1,5,9,9,16,3,10,6,4,14) )

# no error
a1 <- data.frame( "totalWidgets"=c(5,10,9,1,3,1,6,9,6,5,
                                   1,5,9,9,16,3,10,6,4,14),
                  "totalWidgets2"=c(5,10,9,1,3,1,6,9,6,5,
                                   1,5,9,9,16,3,10,6,4,14) )

#Transpose data frame, making a matrix in the process:
a1_t <- t(a1)

#Add dates as column names:
colnames(a1_t) <- c(1646,1647,1648,1649,1650,1651,1652,1653,1654,1655,
  1656,1657,1658,1659,1660,1661,1662,1663,1664,1665)

#Apply detrend:  ERROR APPEARS WHEN I RUN THIS LINE
data.detrend <- detrend(a1_t, tt = 'linear')


Since detrend takes a vector or a matrix,  trydetrend(c(a1_t), tt = 'linear') when there's just one vector.

Can't reproduce this, no issues using pracma2.4.4 in R4.3.3. State a sessionInfo().
